A relationship between the initial precision of an irrational number with the computation of its continued fraction?
Warning: this might be trivial.
Suppose I want to compute the simple continued fraction
$$
[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots]
$$
for a (non quadratic) irrational number $x$.  I can do this numerically very easily, with a computer system allowing arbitrary precision.  But what I don't know is any relationship between computing values of $a_k$, with the initial precision of the number $x$.
This is particularly important in the case of numbers like Champernowne's constant, whose continued fraction contains very large values indeed - $a_{18}$ has 166 digits, $a_{40}$ has 2504 digits, $a_{162}$ has 33102 digits, and so on.  Many of these so called "high water marks" have been computed, see for example by Sikora here and also here.
In general there should be a simple (?) relationship between the correct values of $a_k$ and the initial precision of $x$ - but I don't know what it is.  I'm roughly assuming that if $0<x<1$, then the number of correct integers in the continued fraction will depend on their size: the cumulative sum of their lengths must be less than the precision of $x$.  But I'm enough of an idiot not to know if that's true.  But is it?

Do you have Khinchin's little book?

Yes I do, and I'd completely forgotten about it - many thanks for the reminder!

Short version: knowing a real number to a certain number of decimal places means that it lies in a particular interval bounded by two fractions, which have exact continued fractions; we get accurate partial quotients as long as those two continued fractions coincide, and precious little else.
Long version, by example: Consider $e \approx 2.718281828$. This 10-digit decimal approximation to $e$ means that
$$
e\in [2.7182818275,2.7182818285) = \biggl[ \frac{1087312731}{400000000}, \frac{5436563657}{2000000000} \biggr).
$$
The endpoints have (terminating) continued fractions
\begin{align*}
\frac{1087312731}{400000000} &= [\color{blue}{2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1},\color{red}{1,1,17,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,7}] \\
\frac{5436563657}{2000000000} &= [\color{blue}{2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1},\color{red}{12,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,4}].
\end{align*}
Therefore we know that $e = [\color{blue}{2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1},\color{red}{a_{14},a_{15},a_{16},\ldots}]$, where $1\le a_{14}\le 12$, but we have absolutely no information about $a_{15},a_{16},\ldots$.
We can check that this is consistent with the true continued fraction
$$
e = [\color{blue}{2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1},\color{red}{10,1,1,12,1,1,14,1,\dots}]
$$
(yes, this pattern continues, amazingly).

Many thanks indeed - that is quite a good way of looking at it.  (And I do know about the pattern of the digits in the continued fraction of e.)

Let's start with $a_0 = \lfloor x \rfloor$.  In order to know this correctly, you need $a_0 \le x < a_0 + 1$.  The required "precision" depends on how close $x$ happens to be to an integer: if what you know is $|x - x_0| < \epsilon$, this is sufficient if and only if $\epsilon \le \min(\{x_0\}, 1 - \{x_0\})$, where $\{x_0\}$ is the fractional part of $x_0$.  If you're unlucky enough that $x_0$ is an integer, no $\epsilon > 0$ at all will work.
Now suppose you do know $a_0$.  Write $x = a_0 + 1/t$ where $t = 1/(x - x_0)$.
To know $a_1 = \lfloor t \rfloor$, you need $a_1 \le t < a_1 + 1$, i.e.
$a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + 1} < x \le a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1}$.  So, if you know
$|x - x_0| < \epsilon$, the requirement is that
$$  \epsilon < \min \left( x_0 - a_0 - \frac{1}{a_1 + 1}, \; a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1} - x_0 \right) $$
And so on.  To know $a_0, a_1, \dots a_n$, you need
$$\epsilon < \min \left( \left| x_0 - [a_0; a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n]\right|,\; \left|x_0 - [a_0; a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{n-1},a_{n}+1]\right|\right) $$

Thank you!  I should have been able to work that out for myself, and it makes good sense.
